# HeapCreate with dwMaximumSize > 4GB

Tags: windows, winapi, heap-memory

Is there any way to create a heap that is larger than 4 GB using the `HeapCreate()` function?

A heap bigger than 4 GB can be achieved by setting the `dwMaximumSize` parameter to zero and then asking for memory chunks. But this causes the individual parts of the heap to be split by the `MEM_RESERVED` chunks. I would need to create a continuous heap that has 5GB and is not divided by these `MEM_RESERVED` chunks.

The `HeapCreate()` function's `dwMaximumSize` parameter is of the `SIZE_T` type, which should allow setting this value to a higher value than 4 GB on a 64-bit system. However, when I try to allocate such a heap (larger than 4GB), `HeapCreate()` returns a null pointer. However, I haven't found anywhere documented that the `HeapCreate()` function should only allow the allocation of a heap that has `dwMaximumSize` parameter less than 4GB.

Comment: Possibly related:: [64 bit large mallocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833234/). I found this particularly interesting: [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases): "*User-mode virtual address space for each 64-bit process: Limit in 64-bit Windows: With IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set (default): 7-128 TB (depending on CPU and OS version). **2 GB with IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE cleared***" I wonder if that is really true, or if it is a typo?

Comment: Not necessarily your problem, but the size of `SIZE_T` depends on the bitness of the application, not just the system. A 32-bit app is still limited to 32 bit address space even if run on a 64-bit system.

Comment: I am compiling the app as a 64-bit application

Comment: What's the point of creating a new heap for the application? What does HeapAlloc() return when passed a higher than 4GB size?